# What is pending.schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

https://pending.schema.org/ says:

> The pending extension is a staging area for work-in-progress terms which have yet to be accepted into the core vocabulary.

I'm really new on all this thing, so this short description still leaves me with some doubts in the head. My questions are:

- What's the difference between `pending.schema.org` and `schema.org`?

I saw that BBC NEWS are using the pending.schema.org, but only on JSON-LD.

Comment: You tagged this post as "SEO" but there is no SEO benefit to using most schema.   Google never ranks sites with schema better, it just uses a few schema to gather data to implement rich snippets that give your site a special appearance in the search results.

Comment: So what do you mean by "works the same way as schema.org"?   Are you talking about using the same syntax?  Or are you talking about which schema are official?  Or are you asking about which schema could give you rich snippets?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller What is the difference btw both.

Comment: I edited your question to provide the source of the quote (i.e., the homepage of pending.schema.org). As you said you got this from Google, I’m not sure if you read the rest of the text on pending.schema.org -- did you? It provides some more details.

Comment: @unor Yea, i also updated my question, as i expected the **"definitions could still change significantly after community and steering group review"**  but i want to know if this is the only thing different btw `pending.schema.org` and `schema.org`. Example: Google prioritizes websites that use `schema.org` instead of  `pending.schema.org`?

Answer (score 1):

https://pending.schema.org is for all intents and purposes a site of draft schemas which have not yet been generally accepted by the wider community. It is useful for seeing proposed schema changes or proposed new schema's and to enter discussions on them but schema changes on pending are still subject to change.

I would not recommend implemending schema's from pending into a production environment as they can and do change depending on feedback from the wider stakeholder community. If you choose to use schema's from pending it is best to keep an eye on the particular schema changes you are using and update your implementation as new changes are introduced to the proposed schema so as to ensure that your schema remains valid should the time come that it becomes generally accepted or if your site is being consumed by services which use the pending schema's site.

Answer (score 1):

A pending.schema is a standard area for checkout schema structure which yet to accept core vocabulary. Here you can change pending work easily before the update. It called a temporary schema.